# enum в двух словах

Tags: java, enum

Как он работает? В чем польза от применения enum с практической точки зрения?

Comment: [Посмотри тут](http://www.quizful.net/post/java_enums))))

Comment: Где понятней что происходит, тут: `direction = -1`, или тут: `direction = DIRECTION_LEFT`?

Comment: @PinkTux, это джава, тут енумы - не числа.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так я и не говорю, что в обоих случаях `direction` одного типа :)

Comment: @PinkTux, я имел в виду, что енумы в джаве - это _совсем_ не числа. В отличие от си, плюсов и, даже, шарпа.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а что это меняет? OK, расширю свой пример (мне казалось, что для наглядности и кастрированой записи хватит): `int direction = -1` vs `Direction direction = Direction.DIRECTION_LEFT`.

Comment: @PinkTux, я не о синтаксисе, а о том, что в джаве внутренней реализацией енума числа не являются. Там некий класс с инстансами, и в него можно что-то напихать. Подробнее и сам не знаю, т. к. не джавист.

Answer (score 2):

`Enum` (перечисления) используются когда необходимо некое ограниченное множество значений.

Польза от него заключается как минимум в том, что он повышает удобочитаемость кода.

Также стоит отметить, что перечисления в Java могут содержать конструкторы, методы и переменные экземпляра.

Подробнее о перечислениях Вы можете почитать вот [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/101280/), а лучше в любой классической книге по Java.

Comment: Основная польза, наверное, в том, что нельзя выйти за пределы этого ограниченого множества значений, зато можно по ним итерироваться

Answer (score 0):

Объявив перечисление, можно создавать переменные как и переменные примитивных типов.

```
enum  Apple  { 
    Jonathan,  GoldenDel,  RedDel,  Winesap,  Cortland, Unknown
} 

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class ShowApple {

    static String WELLCOM = "Введите запрос: ";
    PrintWriter printWriter =new PrintWriter(System.out, true);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String choice;
        ShowApple showApple = new ShowApple();

        /*Создаем переменную и выводим ее значение*/
        Apple appleExample = Apple.Cortland;
        showApple.printWriter.println("Значение appleExample: "
                                                 + appleExample);

       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
                                       InputStreamReader(System.in));

        do {
            showApple.printWriter.println(WELLCOM);
            choice = bufferedReader.readLine(); // читаем строку
            showApple.openAppleBase(showApple.name(choice));
        } while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));
    }

/*Метод name возвращает значение определенные в перечисление*/
    Apple name(String appleName){
        if(appleName.equalsIgnoreCase("Jonathan"))
        {
            return Apple.Jonathan;
        }else if (appleName.equalsIgnoreCase("Golden Delicious")){
            return Apple.GoldenDel;
        }else if (appleName.equalsIgnoreCase("Red Delicious")){
            return Apple.RedDel;
        }else if (appleName.equalsIgnoreCase("Winesap")){
            return Apple.Winesap;
        }else if (appleName.equalsIgnoreCase("Cortland")){
           return Apple.Cortland;
        }
        return Apple.Unknown;
    }

    void openAppleBase(Apple appleName) {
       /* Значения перечислимого типа можно использовать, например, в операторе switch*/
        switch (appleName){ 
            case Jonathan:
               printWriter.println("Jonathan - красный");
               break;
            case GoldenDel:
               printWriter.println("Golden Delicious - красный");
               break;
            case RedDel:
               printWriter.println("Red Delicious - красный");
               break;
            case Winesap:
               printWriter.println("Winesap - красный");
               break;
            case Cortland:
               printWriter.println("Cortland - красный");
               break;
            default:
               printWriter.println("Неизвестный сорт");
               break;
        }
    }
}
```